# Physics2D.OverlapBox always returning true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm coding a system to check if a player is in a certain area next to the enemy. I decided to use `Physics2D.OverlapBox`, but when I test it, no matter what, it always returns true.

Here's the code:

```
public bool isNear = false;

private Vector2 nearRadius;

public float nearRadiusLength;

public LayerMask playerLayer;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    isNear = Physics2D.OverlapBox(transform.position, nearRadius,playerLayer);
}
```

Comment: Going by the code above you haven't set nearRadius to be anything, you've just created it as a Vector2. Surely it needs some information regarding distance, etc?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Steve in the comment, you're using the variable nearRadius in your function, but it's a private variable and its value is not being set. Try to make it `public` and set its value in the inspector.

Also take a look at the [Physics2D.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html) documentation, the parameter **angle** seems not optional.

For instance you can set the angle to 0 in the method call:

```
public bool isNear = false;
public Vector2 nearRadius;
public LayerMask playerLayer;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    isNear = Physics2D.OverlapBox(transform.position, nearRadius, 0f, playerLayer);
}
```

And last but not least, make sure the layer from the game object which is holding the script is **not** marked in the defined layer mask `playerLayer`, otherwise the `Physics2D.OverlapBox` will detect the collision with it too.

Comment: To be exact how the OP had it the `playerLayer` value was used for the `angle` parameter (implicitly typecasted to float) and the default `DefaultRaycastLayers` as `layerMask`

Comment: @derHugo, exactly!